# Parameterized RMarkdown File Name

Tags: r, r-markdown, parameterized

I am trying to use 1 parameterized RMarkdown file to run 3 reports and output a different file name for each report (e.g. Report_A.html, Report_B.html, Report_C.html).

I have tried modifying the knit hook of the YAML, but am unable to get it to resolve the parameters.

I do not want to create a separate R file to loop through the parameters.

So far I have the following and the title is parameterized but the report name is Report_`r params$site`_2019-12-12.html

```
params:
  site: "A"
title:  "Report `r params$site`"
knit: (function(inputFile, encoding) {
      rmarkdown::render(inputFile,
      output_file=paste0("Report_", `r params$site`, "_", Sys.Date(),'.html')) })
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated - thank you!

Comment: How exactly are you planning on chancing the param input? You state that you do not want a separate script, do you use a Shiny GUI or are you going to manually change the param?

Comment: I could manually change the param, but would want the filename to reflect the parameter. I realize the loop couldn't be automated, but would like the file name to be if possible.

Comment: Hm I don't know. Such an approach sounds a bit (to be honest, it should be very) unreproducible. Anyhow, the knit hook you use is a very undocumented one, the very few examples I found were different from what you try to achieve. Maybe someone with more experience knows how to exactly deal with this function. But to me it feels a bit like you are trying to use a function for something for which it is not necessarily made.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe don't call 'r ...' in :

```
output_file=paste0("Report_", `r params$site`, "_", Sys.Date(),'.html')) })
```

as in:

```
output_file=paste0("Report_", params$site, "_", Sys.Date(),'.html')) })
```